# Дан массив целых чисел. Выведите все элементы массива в порядке неубывания суммы цифр

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Задача:

[image]

---

Вот код, не могу найти ошибку.
Все работает, но когда отправляю на проверку выдает ошибку.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
here using namespace std;
    struct arrayInfo
     {
        int  mas1;
        int  mas2; 
    };
    int main()
    {
        freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
        freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
        int  size;
        cin>>size;
        int sum=0;
        int s=0;
        int k=1;
        arrayInfo *arr =new arrayInfo[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i].mas1;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            while((arr[i].mas1/k)%10!=0)
            {
                s=(arr[i].mas1/k)%10;
                sum=sum+s;
                k=k*10;
            }
            arr[i].mas2=abs(sum);
            k=1;
            sum=0;
        }


        for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
            for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
            {
                if(arr[i].mas2>arr[i+1].mas2)
                {
                    arrayInfo temp=arr[i];
                    arr[i]=arr[i+1];
                    arr[i+1]=temp;
                }
            }

            for(int j=0;j<size-1;j++)
            for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
            {
                if(arr[i].mas2==arr[i+1].mas2)
                if(arr[i].mas1>arr[i+1].mas1)
                {
                    int t=arr[i].mas1;
                    arr[i].mas1=arr[i+1].mas1;
                    arr[i+1].mas1=t;
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
                cout<<arr[i].mas1<<" ";

    }
```

Comment: Код не учитывает, что в середине числа может быть 0. Вообще рекомендую стандартные функции сортировки и переписать вычисление суммы цифр в отдельную функцию.

Comment: @pavel да кто ж будет стандартные функции использовать в [tag:учебное-задание].

Comment: @pavel "вылить воду из чайника, чем свести задачу к предыдущей" :)

Answer (score 2):

Раз уж дело касается C++, лучше и реализовывать в терминах C++, а не C. Код наглядный, гибкий и понятный.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class specialLess {
public:
    bool operator()(int rhs, int lhs) const {

        unsigned rhsSum = specialSum(rhs);
        unsigned lhsSum = specialSum(lhs);

        if(rhsSum != lhsSum) {
            return rhsSum < lhsSum;
        }

        return rhs < lhs;
    }

private:
    unsigned specialSum(int val) const {

        unsigned result(0);
        val = abs(val);

        while(val >= 1) {
            result += val % 10;
            val /= 10;
        }

        return result;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //std::vector<int> numbers{123, -129, 211};
    std::vector<int> numbers{21, 3, 81, 27};

    std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), specialLess());

    for(int item : numbers) {
        std::cout << item << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Если можно инклюдить:**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int sum(int n) {
    n = abs(n);
    int sum = 0;
    while(n) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

bool s(int x,int y) {
     int s1 = sum(x);
     int s2 = sum(y);
     return (s1 < s1) || (s1 == s2 && x<y);
}

int main() {
    vector<int> vec;
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    ofstream fout("output.txt");
    int size;
    fin >> size; // он нам не нужен:D
    copy(istream_iterator<int>(fin), istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter(vec));
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), s);
    copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(fout," "));
}
```

PS. если нельзя использовать какие-то ф-ции - могу чуть подправить.